# How to set a field will be change by if statement in models for Django?

Tags: python, django, if-statement, django-models

I have a field in models that the True/False value will be affect by other field. May I know how to set it?

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
  storage_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  if storage_amount == 0 or None:
    out_of_storage_or_not = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  else:
    out_of_storage_or_not = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
class Product(models.Model):
    storage_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    out_of_storage_or_not = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.out_of_storage_or_not = False if self.storage_amount else True
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Product(models.Model):
    storage_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    out_of_storage_or_not = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
      if self.storage_amount==0 or None:
        self.out_of_storage_or_not=True
      super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It will return the error:'bool' object has no attribute 'save'. May I know what's that mean?

Comment: this save method is the method get run after our model is saved try to edit it